# Optimizing Airflow Task that transfers data from BigQuery into MongoDB

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, airflow

I need to improve the performance of an Airflow task that transfers data from BigQuery to MongoDB. The relevant task in my `DAG` uses a `PythonOperator`, and simply calls the following python function to transfer a single table/collection:

```
def transfer_full_table(table_name):
    start_time = time.time()

    # (1) Connect to BigQuery + Mongo DB
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    cluster = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
    db = cluster["dbname"]
    print(f'(1) Connected to BQ + Mongo: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')

    # (2)-(3) Run the BQ Queries
    full_query = f"select * from `gcpprojectid.models.{table_name}`"
    results1 = bq.query(full_query)
    print(f'(2) Queried BigQuery: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')
    results = results1.to_dataframe()
    print(f'(3) Converted to Pandas DF: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')

    # (4) Handle Missing DateTimes   # Can we refactor this into its own function?
    datetime_cols = [key for key in dict(results.dtypes) if is_datetime(results[key])]
    for col in datetime_cols:
        results[[col]] = results[[col]].astype(object).where(results[[col]].notnull(), None)
    print(f'(4) Resolved Datetime Issue: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')

    # (5) And Insert Properly Into Mongo
    db[table_name].drop()
    db[table_name].insert_many(results.to_dict('records'))
    print(f'(5) Wrote to Mongo: {round(time.time() - start_time, 5)}')
```

The DAG is setup to transfer many tables from BigQuery to MongoDB (one transfer for each task), and this particular `transfer_full_table` function is meant to transfer an entire singular table, so it simply:

- queries entire BQ table
- converts to pandas, fixes type issue
- drop previous MongoDB collection and reinsert

I am attempting to use this function on a table that is 60MB in size, and here is the performance of the various parts of the task:

```
(1) Connected to BQ + Mongo: 0.0786
(2) Queried BigQuery: 0.80595
(3) Converted to Pandas DF: 87.2797
(4) Resolved Datetime Issue: 88.33461
(5) Wrote to Mongo: 213.92398
```

Steps 3 and 5 are taking all of the time. The task very quickly connects to BQ and Mongo (1), and BQ can very quickly query this table at 60MB (2). However, when I convert to a pandas dataframe (3) (needed for (4) to handle a `type` issue I was having), this step takes ~86.5 seconds. Resolving the date-time issue is then very fast (4), however at the end, dropping the previous MongoDB collection and re-inserting the new pandas dataframe into MongoDB (5) then takes (213.9 - 88.3) = ~125 seconds.

I am seeking any tips, either on the Pandas or on the MongoDB end, as to how I can optimize for these two bottlenecks.

Comment: Any way you could simplify this for us? Hard to debug your specific airflow + bigquery + pandas serialization + mongo situation, but it seems like this may be mostly an issue with `results1.to_dataframe()` and either `db[table_name].insert_many(big_dict)` or with `big_dict = results.to_dict('records')`. Could you break this latter part down further and maybe create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably only in pandas with some setup/teardown? I expect this is just an issue converting a 60MB frame.

Comment: Can you try out pandas_gbq to extract data from BigQuery to Pandas and check if that improves the time for creating pandas dataframe?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado creating a reproducible example for the pandas `to_dataframe()` conversion is easy, yes. Would need to setup a small db to make mongo `insert_many` reproducible...

Comment: For sure. Performance will also obviously be highly dependent on your setup. Is this all on localhost? Or within the same datacenter? Or is there cross-region transfer happening here?

Comment: I am currently running all of this on localhost, yes.

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal I reran the python query using `pandas_gbq.read()` instead of `bq.query()` and it took approximately the same amount of time. If I could insert `results1 = bq.query(full_query)` directly into mongoDB without having to convert to pandas dataframe, that would be great. Is this possible? `results1` is of type `<class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob'>`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that asynchronous operations are muddying your profiling.

The docs on `bq.query` state that the resulting [`google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob) object is an *asyncronous* query job. This means that, after the query is submitted, the python interpreter does not block until you try to use the results of the query with one of the syncronous `QueryJob` methods, `to_dataframe()`. A significant share of the 87 seconds you're seeing is likely just spent waiting for the query to return.

You could wait for the query to be complete by calling `QueryJob.done` iteratively until it returns true, then call your 2nd profiling print statement.

This isn't quite an optimization of your code, but hopefully helps move in the right direction. It's possible some tuning of the pandas roundtrip could help, but I think it's likely that most of your time is being spent waiting for read/write from your databases, and that writing more efficient or a larger number of smaller queries is going to be your only option for cutting down the total time.